# autoplot in ggfortify - only plotting some values for PCA

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

i'm following this documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_pca.html) to run PCA on the iris data set.

```
library(ggfortify)
df <- iris[1:4]
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)

autoplot(pca_res, data = iris, colour = 'Species')
```

I ran the above code and I get three clusters which are colored by species. I only want to plot a specific species. How can I only plot where the species is setosa in this context?

Answer (score 0):

As the object returned by `autoplot` is a `ggplot` object one option would be to manually filter the data passed to the `geom_point` layer under the hood. In your case this is quite simple as the `ggplot` has only one layer which we can access via `p$layers[[1]]` and the data used for this layer via `p$layers[[1]]$data`.

```r
library(ggfortify)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

df <- iris[1:4]
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)

p <- autoplot(pca_res, data = iris, colour = 'Species')

p$layers[[1]]$data <- p$layers[[1]]$data[p$layers[[1]]$data$Species == "setosa", ]

p
```

[image]

**EDIT** Another option would be to "remove" the undesired categories by making the invisible. This way the original scale of the axes will be preserved. Of course would it also be possible to use the approach with filtering but additionally setting the scale to the one used for the unfiltered data.

```r
p + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("versicolor" = "transparent", "virginica" = "transparent", setosa = "red"), breaks = "setosa")
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome - but it's not on the same scale as the original plot - I would like it to show setosa on the same scale as original plot... is that posisble?

Comment: Sure is this possible. See my edit for one option which additionally doesn't require to manipulate the ggplot2 object.